# Google Charts: Plotting mutiple "Y" values on same "X" value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I am using scatter plot of Google Charts.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

I am plotting values against named entities (On X axis). The entities can have multiple Blue/Red values. Referring to the screenshot above, I would like the blue dot to plot above A1, instead of A1 getting duplicated.

Can this be done? 
Here is my code:

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          
        

          // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        
          data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Blue Value');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Red Value');
          data.addRows([
            ['A1', 3500, 4500],
            ['A1', 4000, null],
            ['A2', 3700, 4100],
            ['A3', 3110, 4200],
            ['A4', 3600, 4300]
          ]);

          // Set chart options
          var options = {'title':'My Title',
              'width':800,
              'height':500};

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, a *discrete* axis (string values) will show all x-axis values,
even if they repeat

to get the desired chart, you could use a *continuous* axis (number values),
and use object notation to format the values and the axis labels (`ticks`)

object notation allows you to provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

```
{v: 1, f: 'A1'}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue Value');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red Value');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 1, f: 'A1'}, 3500, 4500],
    [{v: 1, f: 'A1'}, 4000, null],
    [{v: 2, f: 'A2'}, 3700, 4100],
    [{v: 3, f: 'A3'}, 3110, 4200],
    [{v: 4, f: 'A4'}, 3600, 4300]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Title',
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      ticks: [
        {v: 0.5, f: ''},
        {v: 1, f: 'A1'},
        {v: 2, f: 'A2'},
        {v: 3, f: 'A3'},
        {v: 4, f: 'A4'}
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```